# Split a string using variable pattern

Tags: python, html, string, split

I need to extract tags and texts from the dialogs in a srt file, for example, in:

```
'<b><font color="#ca6500">FEMALE VOICE:</font></b> <i>The world is changed.</i>'
```

I want to get:

```
['<b>', '<font color="#ca6500">', 'FEMALE VOICE:', '</font>', '</b>', ' ', '<i>', 'The world is changed.', '</i>']
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using HTML parser here. Can you use `beautifulsoup` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment above suggests, you might want to use Beautiful Soup here.  That being said, for text with only singly nested top level HTML tags, regex can cope reasonably well.  Here is an `re.findall` approach:

```py
inp = '<b><font color="#ca6500">FEMALE VOICE:</font></b> <i>The world is changed.</i>'
matches = re.findall(r'<.*?>|.+?(?=<|$)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['<b>', '<font color="#ca6500">', 'FEMALE VOICE:', '</font>', '</b>', ' ',
 '<i>', 'The world is changed.', '</i>']
```

The regex pattern used says to:

```regex
<.*?>       match an HTML tag
|           OR
.+?(?=<|$)  match all content until reaching either the nearest HTML tag or
            the end of the input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! perfect answer - brief and well explained.